# Open new Activity using LoaderManager, RecyclerAdapter, Intent and Database

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-loadermanager

I am writing a program using Database, LoaderManager, RecyclerAdapter and Intent. The problem is whenever a item in adapter is clicked it causes java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object returned from onCreateLoader must not be null error.

```
package com.abhi.mynotekeeper;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager;
import androidx.loader.content.CursorLoader;
import androidx.loader.content.Loader;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

public class NavigationSample extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    RecyclerView noteList;
    NoteKeeperOpenHelper noteKeeperOpenHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor noteCursor;
    NoteRecyclerAdapter noteRecyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_sample);

        noteList = findViewById(R.id.note_list);
        noteKeeperOpenHelper = new NoteKeeperOpenHelper(this);
        noteList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(0, null, this);

        displayNote();

    }

    private void displayNote() {
       // db = noteKeeperOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
       // noteCursor = db.query(NoteKeeperDatabaseContract.NoteInfoEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        noteRecyclerAdapter = new NoteRecyclerAdapter(this, null);

        noteList.setAdapter(noteRecyclerAdapter);

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, @Nullable Bundle args) {
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = null;
        if (id == 0) {
            cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this) {

                @Override
                public Cursor loadInBackground() {
                    db = noteKeeperOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                    Cursor cursor = db.query(NoteKeeperDatabaseContract.NoteInfoEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
                    return cursor;
                }
            };
        }

        Log.i("NoteActivity", "OnCreateLoader Running");
        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        noteRecyclerAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        Log.i("NoteActivity", "onLoadfinish Running");

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        if (loader.getId() == 0) {
            noteRecyclerAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        }
        Log.i("NoteActivity", "Onloaderreset Running");


    }
}
```

NoteRecyclerAdpater Class code

```
package com.abhi.mynotekeeper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class NoteRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private final Context context;
    List<Notes> notesList;
    Cursor mCursor;

    public NoteRecyclerAdapter(Context context, Cursor mCursor) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mCursor = mCursor;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NoteRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycleview_note_list, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            return;
        }
        String noteTitle = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(NoteKeeperDatabaseContract.NoteInfoEntry.COLUMN_NOTE_TITLE));
        String noteText = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(NoteKeeperDatabaseContract.NoteInfoEntry.COLUMN_NOTE_TEXT));
        int noteId = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(NoteKeeperDatabaseContract.NoteInfoEntry.COLUMN_ID));
        holder.courseTitle.setText(noteTitle);
        holder.courseText.setText(noteText);
        holder.noteId = noteId;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return mCursor.getCount();

    }

    public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor){
        if(mCursor!=null){
            mCursor.close();
        }
        mCursor = cursor;

        if(cursor!= null){
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView courseTitle, courseText;
        public int noteId;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            courseTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            courseText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NoteActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("position", noteId);

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Need help to resolve the error.

I tried searching over the web but unable to find the solution of the problem.

Comment: The reason for that is in the `loadInBackground` method that you have overridden, `db.query(...)` is returning null. Since that is something dependent on `NoteKeeperOpenHelper` and `NoteKeeperDatabaseContract`, you might need to check those classes.